# Here Traffic information in the form of JOSN format

Tags: api, maps, here-api, here-traffic

Is there any we can get the traffic information in the form of json data, because currently here api gives response in the form of png image which is difficult to process.

Below one is the traffic request of Here api
https://1.traffic.maps.ls.hereapi.com/maptile/2.1/traffictile/newest/normal.day/14/8683/5379/256/png8?apiKey=xxxx&min_traffic_congestion=heavy

Reference : https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-tile/dev_guide/topics/example-traffic.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Traffic Rest API and it returns data in XML or JSON. More details -> https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/dev_guide/topics_v6.1/resource-parameters-flow.html